# Как сосчитать строчки в txt документе в Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, mac

Нужен код для Python 3 чтобы сосчитать строчки в txt документе.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошим решением будет посчитать количество переводов строк (`'\n'`) и прибавить единицу.

***Пример:***

*file.txt:*

```html
Hello, World!
Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!Ni!
Spam!
Eggs
```

*Код:*

```py
with open('file.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    lines = text.count('\n') + 1

print(lines)
```

*stdout:*

```html
4
```

**UPD:**
Код можно оптимизировать.

Вот версия, которая в большинстве случаев будет использовать меньше памяти:

```py
with open('test.txt') as f:
    n = 0
    for line in f:
        n += 1

print(n)
```

На каждой итерации в памяти хранится только одна строка (прошлые с аппетитом съедает сборщик мусора)

Но тут следует понимать, что может попасться файл с небольшим количеством строк (или вовсе с одной). В таком случае наша оптимизация не даст никаких результатов.

---

Тогда оптимальным вариантом будет чтение файла по некоторому количеству данных:

```py
with open('test.txt') as f:
    n = 1
    text = True
    while text:
        text = f.read(8)
        n += text.count('\n')

print(n)
```

Этот способ потенциально экономит очень много памяти. При желании, можно считывать хоть по символу. Но тогда мы незначительно, но проигрываем по скорости.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант без загрузки файла в память целиком:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    quantity = sum(1 for line in f)

print(quantity)
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте методы `readlines()` и `len()`:

```
with open ('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    quantity = len(file.readlines())
```